# Keydown event Jquery node js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to work on a chat application and I was learning to work with `socket.io` in nodejs. Now, I have been able to display 'a typing message' when a user presses down any keys on the keyboard. But lets say when the user stops typing for a moment or clicks on the enter button to send the message, I want to invoke a keyup or key release event. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to change the text inside my `<em>` tags. It still displays 'user is typing' even after the user has pressed send.

```
message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
});

message.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em></em></p>';
});


socket.on('typing', function(data){
  feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message...</em></p>';
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more applicable if you check if the user input box is not empty and then display "User is typing"?

Comment: That would not work. If the user types in a text, but then pauses for a minute, it would still say typing, even if the user switched to another tab

Comment: @NicolaiSchmid:- Yes that's the problem that I am facing

Comment: I don't think using the keyup event is a good idea in general since it's invoked every time the user releases a key. You definitely have to add some sort of debouncing for ~200ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` function. So when user stops typing, the event will be fired for example after 500ms and you can handle it properly in backend. When user starts typing the `timeout` will be cleared and event `stopped typing` will not be sent to the backend.

I provide code with the idea above.

```
var timeout;
$("#input").keyup(function() {
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){ socket.emit("stopped typing") }, 500);
});

$("#input").keydown(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

Comment: That's what I meant by debouncing